# RPM Maker(creator) problem to extract file from program

Tags: windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqxUT.jpg)
Eror:Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. f you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

```
Value of '2' is not valid for "Value", "Value" should be between 'minimum and maximum. Parameter name: Value.
    ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
    mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
    RMPMaker
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/RMPMaker/RMPMaker.exe
----------------------------------------
    System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
    System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9220.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
    System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
    System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
    System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9220.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
    System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

    ************** JIT Debugging **************
    To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
    application or computer (machine.config) must have the
    jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
    he application must also be compiled with debugging
    enabled.
```

```
When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.


I tried running the department commander's program on the computer and everything works. I asked to check the data, and it is correct. The program is licensed, so there is no way to reinstall it. I can't collect logs from the commander's computer because I don't have access to military secrets of that level.
```